# How do I safely shutdown the daemon in ubuntu?

Tags: monerod, daemon, linux

I have started monerd detached and need to exit it safely. I have tried adding stop to the /proc/(pid of monderod)/fd/0 but monerod doesn't accept the input. Is it ok to kill the process? I want to restart monerod in screen so I can more easily attach/detach to send commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem in forcibly stopping `monerod`, the daemon is constantly writing the received blocks into the disk and LMDB is one of the most robust databases on the market, it doesn't corrupt easily unless there is a hardware problem, only thing that doesn't get saved are the IP bans but this will be fixed in a next release. 
To make sure everything is saved type `exit` in the daemon window.